# How to handle sharepoint web services exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, exception, web-services

I have developed an application of ***share point***. I am using **web services** for that.

the problem is that while working with my app sometimes i get some exceptions.
like,

> **Exception** of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException'
> was thrown.
>
> **Stack Strace ::**    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
> message, WebResponse response, Stream
> responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
> at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
> methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
> ......... my methods

From this exception i cannot understand the main problem. While developing i can debug the code, but now my application is getting launched..i can get error log file from my client which contains this type of excetions.

But how to catch exact error.???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(VS.71).aspx) to On in your web.config file.

There is a good discussion in the comments of this article - [SoapException sucks](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2005/06/02/9712.aspx) - about different ways to get the detail of exception thrown within SOAP methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you analyzed what the innerException contains ?

```
try
{
 // do your web server thingies here
}
catch (SoapServerException ssx)
{
 if (ssx.InnerException != null)
 {
  string message = ssx.InnerException.Message;
 }
}
```

Regards,

Magnus